# Why isinstance(num, int) returns True for float value num = 7.0

Tags: python, function, types

Can anyone explain what action does this

```
return  num.is_integer()
```

return statement perform?

The code below is for checking that the given value is integer or not but it's also returning True for values like 7.0, 5.0, 9.0 which should have been float.

In the code below, for values like

num = 7 --------- it returns True which is understandable.

num = 7.5 ----------- it returns False which i didn't get why.

num = 7.0 ----------- it also returns True which I didn't get why.

```
def is_integer(num):
    if isinstance(num, float):
        return num.is_integer()
    elif isinstance(num, int):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: `isinstance(7.0, int)` *doesn't* return `True`, nor does `is_integer(7.0)` even get that far.

Comment: @chepner `a = 7.0; a.is_integer()` → `True`.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, I know. That's the point: `(7.0).is_integer()` is what makes `is_integer` return `True`, not `isinstance(7.0, int)`.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, but that's not what I read from your first comment. Good you clarified.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "can anyone explain what action does this {return num.is_integer()} return statement is performing." [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) in order to understand what `is_integer` does?

Comment: "num = 7.5 -----------it returns False which i didn't get why?" Do you think it should return True instead? Why? Just to be clear: do you understand *what an integer is*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a function (with an `if-elif` chain) defined such as:

```py
def is_integer(num):
    if isinstance(num, float):
        return num.is_integer()
    elif isinstance(num, int):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Which, is coincidentally equivalent to:

```py
def is_integer(num):
    if isinstance(num, float):
        return num.is_integer()
    if isinstance(num, int):
        return True
    return False
```

##### How it works

Here is the pseudo-code for the above logic.

- If `num` is (or is *subclass* of) a float:

  - return `True` if it represents an integer value, such as `7.0`
  - else, return `False`
- If `num` is (or is *subclass* of) an int, return `True`
- If `num` is any other type, return `False`

##### Inputs

Thus, for the given inputs:

> num = 7 --------- it returns True which is undestandable.

Correct, because `7` is an `int` type.

Now from the above pseudo-code, we can see:

> num = 7.5 -----------it returns False which i didn't get why?

Since `type(7.5)` is float, and `7.5.is_integer()` is `False`.

> num = 7.0 ----------- it also returns True which i didn't get why?

Since `type(7.0)` is float, and `7.0.is_integer()` is `True`.

> num = False ---------- returns True

Since `type(False)` is bool, and `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so we then return `True`.

#### Testing

```py
>>> is_integer(0)
True
>>> is_integer(1234567)
True
>>> issubclass(type(3), int)
True
>>> is_integer(1.2)
False
>>> is_integer(11.01)
False
>>> 3.21.is_integer()
False
>>> is_integer(7.00)
True
>>> 2.0.is_integer()
True
>>> is_integer(True)
True
>>> issubclass(type(False), int)
True
```

#### Resolution

> can anyone explain what action does this `return num.is_integer()` return statement is performing.

It checks if `num`, which is a `float` value, represents an integer or decimal value such that the part after the decimal point `.` is nothing, or `0`.

For example, `float.isinteger()` is true for `123.0` since it is a whole number which does not have a fractional part, but is false for `123.45` since the fractional part is `.45`, which means that the number represents a floating point value instead of an integer value.

Perhaps this could be better illustrated with the following example:

```py
>>> 7.0 == int(7.0)
True
>>> 7.1 == int(7.1)
False
```

Note that `7.0.is_integer()` returns True, since casting the float value to an `int` does not result in data being lost, whereas `int(7.1)` is `7`, hence we have dropped the fractional part which is `.1`, and so `7.1 != 7.0`.

> the given below code is for checking the given value is integer or not but it also returning true for values like 7.0,5.0, 9.0 which should have been float.

This is correct, it is due to the `float.isinteger()` usage as mentioned above, which checks if the float values can be representable as an `int` without any data being lost.

To fix this, you can simply return whether `isinstance(num, int)` is true:

```
def is_integer(num):
    return isinstance(num, int)
```

However, the above does not account for `bool` values, since as mentioned `issubclass(bool, int)` is True. Thus, a check like `isinstance(False, int)` will actually return `True`.

To update it to return `False` for bool values, we can perform a *stricter* type check, only checking if the `type` of num is explicitly an `int`:

```py
def is_integer(num):
    return type(num) is int
```

Finally, to check only for `int` and custom subclasses of `int`, but to exclude `bool` or any subclasses of `bool`, we can update to first check for a `bool` type or subtype, and *then* check for an `int` type or subtype, as shown below.

```py
def is_integer(num):
    if isinstance(num, bool):
        return False
    # else, we *haven't* returned a value yet
    return isinstance(num, int)
```

Answer (score 1):

> num = 7.5 -----------it returns False which i didn't get why?

7.5 is a float value so `is_integer` method checks the value and it is a float. Then the method returns `num.is_integer()` which is False because 7.5 is not an integer.

> num = 7.0 ----------- it also returns True which i didn't get why?

7.0 is a float value too. Then the method returns `num.is_integer()` which is True because it can cast to an integer.

Comment: Be careful with "cast": you can "cast" `7.5` to an integer as well; you just get back `7`. It's more accurate to say that `7.0 == int(7.0)`.

Comment: thanks @Deniz and chepner for the answer as i have recently started learning python and i didn't know that float.is_integer() is built-in types. your answer has helped me a lot thank you.